# not able to hide div

Tags: html

I have combo box which needs to be displayed based on the option i select,

but when i set display none to div it is not getting hidden. what could be the problem.

below is the html code and java script

```
<div id="addBanks" style="display: none" style="overflow: auto;height: 75%">
                        <table id="commonBodyTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="100%" align="center" class="tableBorder2" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="4" class="mainheader">Add Banks</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="darkrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">Bank Code</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" ><input type="text" class="textbox" name="bankcode" id="bankcode" maxlength="20"  /></td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="lightrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">Bank Name</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" ><input type="text" class="textbox" name="bankname" id="bankname" maxlength="20"  /></td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="darkrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">Branch Code</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" ><input type="text" class="textbox" name="branchcode" id="branchcode" maxlength="20"  /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="lightrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">IFSC Code</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" ><input type="text" class="textbox" name="ifsccode" id="ifsccode" maxlength="20"  /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="darkrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">Country</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" class="textfieldalign"><select class="combobox" name="countryid" id="countryid" onchange="getStates(this.value)">
                                                    <option value="" >- - - Select Country Name - - -</option>
                                                </select></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="lightrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">State</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" class="textfieldalign"><select class="combobox" name="stateid" id="stateid">
                                                    <option value="" >- - - Select State Name - - -</option>
                                                </select></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="darkrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">District Name</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" >
                                                <select class="combobox" name="districtid" id="districtid">
                                                    <option value="" >- - - Select District Name - - -</option>
                                                </select></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="lightrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">Town or Village</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign">
                                                Town <input   type="radio" class="textbox" name="optTownOrVillage" id="optTownOrVillage" value="townOpt" onclick="enableVillageOrTown(this)"/>
                                                Village <input type="radio" class="textbox" name="optTownOrVillage" id="optTownOrVillage" value="villageOpt" onclick="enableVillageOrTown(this)"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <div id="villageDiv" style="display: none;">
                                            <tr class="darkrow">
                                                <td width="30%" class="textalign">Village Name</td>
                                                <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                                <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" >
                                                    <select class="combobox" name="villageid" id="villageid">
                                                        <option value="" >- - - Select Village Name - - -</option>
                                                    </select></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </div>

                                        <tr class="darkrow">
                                            <div id="townDiv" style="display: none;">
                                                <td width="30%" class="textalign">Town Name</td>
                                                <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                                <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" >
                                                    <select class="combobox" name="townid" id="townid">
                                                        <option value="" >- - - Select Town Name - - -</option>
                                                    </select></td>
                                            </div>
                                        </tr>


                                        <tr class="darkrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" ><input type="button" class="submitbu" name="save" id="save" value="Save" onclick="saveState()">
                                                    <input type="button" class="submitbu" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelAddState();"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        </td>

                                                        </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        </div>
```

and my java script :

```
function enableVillageOrTown(opt){
                var optionValue = opt.value;
                if(optionValue=='townOpt'){
                     document.getElementById("townDiv").style.display = "";
                     document.getElementById("villageDiv").style.display = 'none';
                }
                if(optionValue=='villageOpt'){
                     document.getElementById("villageDiv").style.display = "";
                     document.getElementById("townDiv").style.display = 'none';
                }

            }
```

UPDATE :

```
<div id="villageDiv" style="display: none;">
                                            <tr class="darkrow">
                                                <td width="30%" class="textalign">Village Name</td>
                                                <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                                <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" >
                                                    <select class="combobox" name="villageid" id="villageid">
                                                        <option value="" >- - - Select Village Name - - -</option>
                                                    </select></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </div>
```

also this is not properly aligned when

```
<tr class="lightrow">
                                            <td width="30%" class="textalign">Town or Village</td>
                                            <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                            <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign">
                                                Town <input   type="radio" class="textbox" name="optTownOrVillage" id="optTownOrVillage" value="townOpt" onclick="enableVillageOrTown(this)"/>
                                                Village <input type="radio" class="textbox" name="optTownOrVillage" id="optTownOrVillage" value="villageOpt" onclick="enableVillageOrTown(this)"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
```

this is not hidden when the page first time loads

Please help me to find the problem

Regards

Comment: Okay, got it but first time it self the div is not hidden though i have set display none

Comment: your update seems the div is hidden when i testing in fiddle...

Comment: No it is not in the application :(

Comment: You can try this in javascript in another method like document.getElementById("villageDiv").css('display', 'none');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, if it works for you

```
function enableVillageOrTown(opt){
                var optionValue = opt.value;
                if(optionValue=='townOpt'){
                     document.getElementById("townDiv").style.display = "";
                     document.getElementById("villageDiv").style.display = "none";
                }
                if(optionValue=='villageOpt'){
                     document.getElementById("villageDiv").style.display = "";
                     document.getElementById("townDiv").style.display = "none";
                }

            }
```

For that your should use this code for HTML

```
<!--<div >-->
                                            <tr class="darkrow" id="villageDiv" style="display: none;">
                                                <td width="30%" class="textalign">Village Name</td>
                                                <td width="5%" class="mandatory">*</td>
                                                <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign" >
                                                    <select class="combobox" name="villageid" id="villageid">
                                                        <option value="" >- - - Select Village Name - - -</option>
                                                    </select></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <!--</div>-->
```

Comment: You are using div in the table that is  wrong, id and style you are using at Div you can use it at TR as well and that will work fine for you

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked, By the way i have not downvoted your answer. and please see my update for option button alignment and help me please

Answer (score 1):

Remove the DIVs that you are trying to manipulate and just hide or show the TRs that contain the drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code you provided and the results are correct: http://jsfiddle.net/6mKtZ/

...meaning that `div id="villageDiv" style="display: none;"` is hidden and the only thing that shows up on the page is "?"